# TableViewController presented modally resists scrolling and is difficult to dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have a TableViewController with dynamic cells which is presented modally via another tableview controller and it "resists" the drag gesture via which modals can be dismissed.

I have tried activating user interaction for all prototype cells but with no result.

Have tried to test quickly with a mock static table and the drag gesture works as usual.

Can it be that the dynamic cells interfere with the gesture in some way?

Is there some property which I may have changed in my dynamic tableview controller and which may affect the modal's ability to dismiss easily?

I set up my tableview like this

```
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
    self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was found to be this line when I set up my `TableViewController`:

```
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

Apparently, disabling bouncing for the tableview kind of deactivates the drag gesture for the modal view.

I set it to true and everything was working, although I think it should be possible to disable bounce and still be able to drag the modal down.